# I see no cookies in request body when ran using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I do not have any login function it's a simple get API https://snapmed.no/

it is complaining as no cookies I added Httpcookiemanager but still, I am facing the same issue!

Comment: What is the error message (complain) you get in the response?

Comment: The response is correct as expected  but why is it showing me as no cookies even though I have correct response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing the very first request my expectation is that you're not supposed to send any request cookies because JMeter always opens the web pages as "clean" user without any cookies, cache, etc.

This happens also with the web browsers

[image]

What HTTP Cookie Manager does is extracting the cookies from the server's [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header

On subsequent requests if there is a match of domain/path/etc. JMeter adds the relevant cookie(s) as [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) request header.

For single simple HTTP request I wouldn't expect any outgoing cookies. If you need to impersonate a returning user with some cookies - you can add them manually.

More information:

- [HTTP State Management Mechanism](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265)
- [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)